# Why does the ↵ enter symbol appear in an array string? in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have Javascript project with `element.addEventListener('click', function(){})`,
so when it clicked that `element.innerText` is pushed to array (at this stage strings works correct on Safari - like `'Name1'`).

And it works fine anywhere besides Safari and iOS browsers. I noticed in Safari console that array looks like `["↵Name1↵","↵Name2↵","↵Name3↵"]` and in other browsers it looks like `["Name1","Name2","Name3"]` which is correct.

Does anybody know why this ↵ enter symbol came out and how to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```js
const text = element.innerText;
array.push(text);
```

use

```js
const text = element.textContent.trim();
array.push(text);
```

See:

- [Differences from `innerText` - `Node.textContent` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#differences_from_innertext)
- [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)